# Convert relative to absolute path

Tags: r, path

Is there a good built-in way to convert relative file paths to absolute paths in R, that doesn't require the path to actually exist on the filesystem?

Both `base::normalizePath` nor `tools::file_path_as_absolute` are looking up physical paths in the filesystem, so they both fail when the path doesn't exist:

```
> normalizePath('foo')
[1] "foo"
Warning message:
In normalizePath("foo") : path[1]="foo": No such file or directory

> tools::file_path_as_absolute('foo')
Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute("foo") : file 'foo' does not exist
```

I can write the following function that does a decent job on Unix-like systems, but isn't cross-platform to a Windows world:

```
rel_to_abs <- function(x) {
  # Convert `x` to absolute path - does not consult the file system
  ifelse(grepl('^/', x), x, file.path(getwd(), x))
}
```

If I've missed something in the core libraries, I'd be happy to be pointed to it.

Comment: how about `path.expand("~/foo")` (dont know how this plays on W's)

Comment: @user20650 That's already an absolute path, just abbreviated.

Comment: @user20650 the problem is that it only works when you're in the home directory, and if you already know what directory you're in, you might as well just prepend that (as in my proposal).

Comment: ah okay, fair enough @Ken. I  misunderstood. Sorry for noise.

Comment: @KenWilliams FWIW on windows `normalizePath("foo")` works fine, it just displays a warning. In your case it also doesn't fail but seems to return the relative path unchanged. To avoid a warning you can call `normalizePath("foo", mustWork = FALSE)`. What is your system and can you confirm to be sure that what you showed here is what you get ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `getAbsolutePath` of the `R.utils` package:

```
> R.utils::getAbsolutePath("foo")
[1] "/home/stla/Work/R/foo"
```

Comment: Looks like this will work fine in common cases, but unfortunately it gets cross-platform cases pretty mixed up.  For example, on Unix it thinks that `C:/foo` is an absolute path (which it would be on Windows), but it's not (it's the `foo` file or directory in the `C:` relative directory).